# Symlink dotfiles with a script

Tags: bash, dotfiles

As many others have done, I want to create a repo to store my dotfile customizations. Instead of doing `ln -s` manually, I am using the following script to set things up.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

DIR="$HOME/Documents/Dotfiles"
OLDDIR="$HOME/Documents/Other\ Files/Dotfiles_old"
FILES=($HOME/.bash_profile)

echo "Creating $OLDDIR for backup of any existing dotfiles in ~"
mkdir -p "$OLDDIR"
echo "…done"

echo "Changing to the $DIR directory"
cd "$DIR"
echo "…done"

for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
echo "Backup dotfile $FILE from ~/ to $OLDDIR"
cp -L "$HOME/$FILE" "$OLDDIR"
done

for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
echo "copy $FILE from ~ to $DIR."
cp -L "$HOME/$FILE $DIR/"
echo "Creating symlink to $FILE from ~ to $DIR."
ln -sfn "$DIR/$FILE" "$HOME/$FILE";
done

shellcheck source "$HOME/.bash_profile"
```

When I run this, `cp` fails because it thinks that `.bash_profile` isn't there, which obviously isn't the case:

[image]

[image]

I think my path to the files may be incorrect, although `shellcheck` reports nothing. What am I forgetting here?

**UPDATE**: Made another run at this - minus the `cp`. The one thing I am still unsure of is the use of `exit`, in particular since I'm already using `-e` to check for errors.

Shellcheck and `bash -n` return 0.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function makeFiles() {
    touch .bash_profile \
    touch .gitconfig \
    touch .gitignore_global
    }

function makeLinks() {
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile \
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig \
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitignore_global ~/.gitignore_global \
    source ~/.bash_profile
    }

    read -rp "This may overwrite existing files. Are you sure? (y/n) " -n 1;
    echo "";
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        makeFiles && makeLinks
    fi;
```

Sigh, `ln` decides that `.bash_profile` needs to be a directory for some crazy reason.

Comment: Why do you think you need all those trailing backslashes??? remove them, it seems you have no idea what they should be used for. As a side note: why are you unsetting the variables `makeFiles`, `unset` and `makeLinks`? another side note: why do you use so many trailing semi-colons?

Answer (score 0):

You're building the path of the dotfile incorrectly - `$FILE` already contains the full path of the dotfile, and there's no need to prepend `$HOME` again. Try with this `cp` command:

```
cp -L "$FILE $DIR/"
```